# Dynamic parameters in Power Automate triggers

Tags: power-automate

I created a Power Automate flow that is triggered by "Item create" in a SharePoint list with the trigger 'When Item is created'

[image]

I don't know how to make the SharePoint site and list name parameterized. I need them stored as some kind of environmental constants or variables.

I know how to use set and initialize variable activities, but I can't use that before the trigger.